# Trying to set MySQL root password results in error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, debian

I'm still very new to MySQL and Debian, but have been reading a lot during the last days.

I have a root account to a virtual machine that I want to use for Wordpress. One thing I read was that I should password protect MySQL because by default root user doesn't need a password for it.

I read someone doing it like this:

```
 mysql> mysqladmin -u root password mypassword;
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqladmin -u     root password mypassword' at line 1
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command straight from the shell, rather than within mysql?

Comment: That might have something to do with it. I restarted my ssh connection and tried some more and finally it worked. Not entirely sure what made it work.

Comment: scottsanders is right, you don't run it from the mysql> shell - but straight from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the command from within mysql, but the command is actually meant to be run directly from the terminal.

`mysqladmin -u root password mypassword`

If you are already in *mysql* within terminal, type `exit` then enter your `mysqladmin` command.